# Android Dongle ADB Shell Recovery Segmentation Fault

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb

I am trying to wipe out data from android dongle with help of ADB commands. When I typed ADB shell command then it will provide me `root@android:/#`.

Now when I type `recovery` or `recovery wipe_data` in command prompt then it will give me segmentation fault error. Why does this error occur, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `adb shell recovery --wipe_data`? See also: [Wipe data/Factory reset through ADB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb)

Comment: I tried but same result "segmentation fault" and during shell command its not able to detect the device but outside from shell its detect